# Ionic / UI router: Navigating to the same state with reload: true breaks the history

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make my ionic app transition within the same state but with different URL. I have a the following state:

```
.state('app.profile.id', {
        url: '/profile/:id',
        data : {
            id: -1
        },
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/pages/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

This is the profile page of a user. What I'm trying to do is to have a link from the profile page to other users profile pages. I'm making the transition with the following code:

```
$state.go('app.profile.id', {id: id}, {reload: true});
```

If I don't add the `reload: true` part, then the data on the page won't refresh since I'm not changing the state. What I understand from `reload: true` is that it forces transition between states.

However my problem is, the back button acts weird after the transition. The back transition doesn't happen at first few levels: It changes the `id` (which is noticeable after a manual refresh), and after one or two level, `$ionicHistory.goBack()` breaks completely.

I think this is a bug in UI router, any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.